# MySQL - issues with population of the table

Tags: mysql

While working on a learning project I faced an impossibility to solve a specific task. I found a workaround, but am now trying eliminate the lack of understanding of my specific problem, so suggestions are highly welcome!

The issue is as follows:

I have a table    user_orders:

```
            CREATE TABLE `user_orders` (
                `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                `user_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
                `start_date` DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
                `due_date` DATE NULL,

               CONSTRAINT `fk_user_orders_user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) 
               ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION 
            ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

After the creation I am trying to populate it (do not pay attention to the approaches I used in population, my aim was to practice as many MySQL solutions as possible to get a thorough overview):

```
  public function run(): void
  {
    $queryString = /** @lang text */
        "
            INSERT INTO `user_orders` (
                `user_id`
            )
            SELECT
                `id`
            FROM 
                `users`;
        ";

    DB::statement($queryString);

    $queryString2 = /** @lang text */
        "
            INSERT INTO `user_orders` (
                `due_date`
            )
            VALUES
                ( '{$this->generateDueDate()}'),
                ( '{$this->generateDueDate()}'),
                ( '{$this->generateDueDate()}'),
                ( '{$this->generateDueDate()}'),
                ( '{$this->generateDueDate()}'),
                ( '{$this->generateDueDate()}'),
                ( '{$this->generateDueDate()}'),
                ( '{$this->generateDueDate()}'),
                ( '{$this->generateDueDate()}'),
                ( '{$this->generateDueDate()}')
        ";

    DB::statement($queryString2);
}
```

My logic was as follows:

- id is autoincremented,
- user_id inserted by INSERT SELECT from users' table
- start_date is created automatically
- after all, populating the due_date field using a php function

I expected the table to get populated properly, however, I am facing an error:

```
 SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a 
 default value (SQL: 
            INSERT INTO `user_orders` (
                `due_date`
            )
            VALUES
                ( '2020-08-06'),
                ( '2020-08-06'),
                ( '2020-08-06'),
                ( '2020-08-06'),
                ( '2020-08-06'),
                ( '2020-08-06'),
                ( '2020-08-06'),
                ( '2020-08-06'),
                ( '2020-08-06'),
                ( '2020-08-06')
        )
```

Why do I see this error? The due_date column is null, why can't I populate it after the all overs are filled?

Comment: *user_id inserted by INSERT SELECT from users' table* how?

Comment: Have a look at the second code snippet, meanin $queryString, I added the migration I use.

Comment: Your second query is only inserting the due date, but the user ID is also expected (which is what your error is saying, `user_id` doesn't have a default value so it is expecting you to provide a value yourself).

Comment: What should I look at? `INSERT INTO `user_orders` ( `due_date`)` is not enough. You must supply values to user_id also.

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) so we can stop guessing.  We need to see example data and expected results aswell.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Raymond, however there is all the info that might be needed to reproduce it.

Comment: *"however there is all the info that might be needed to reproduce it. "* sorry i doubt that  -> `SELECT
                id
            FROM 
                users`  .. Also we don't know what results you are after because now it looks like you want to insert user_orders records with only due_dates

Comment: Raymond - sorry, disagree with you. The information i provided was enough for knowledgeable people get the mistake I made immediately. Users table was not needed here. Though, glad you have represented your position with a downvote to my question :)

Comment: Issue here was with trailing inserts. I am doing some reading on it right now and see that the mistake @AntG have kindly pointed at was quite stupid and is motivated exclusively by my lack of knowledge. No worries about the donwvote! Looks like I deserved it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second query should either be an `UPDATE` or it needs to also insert a `user_id` value because this has no default.  At the moment it is trying to insert 10 additional rows with no value for `user_id`

Your second query may become:

```php
UPDATE `user_order` SET `due_date` = '{$this->generateDueDate()}'
WHERE `due_date` IS NULL
```

This will update any entries that have been added (or are already there with a null due date) with your generated date.

With reference to your comment regarding ON DUPLICATE KEY, you could have a query like this

```php
 INSERT INTO `user_orders` ( `user_id`, `due_date`)
     SELECT `id`, '{$this->generateDueDate()}'
       FROM `users` ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `due_date`= '{$this->generateDueDate()}';
```

(Might need to double check the syntax).
But your Auto-increment breaks this, as your key will always be unique.  Otherwise it would insert your rows from the users table with the generated Due Date, but if the user already exists it will simply update the due date.

Comment: @AntG Got the mistake. I somehow assumed that INSERT will do the trick UPDATE does, my bad.

Comment: *"I somehow assumed that INSERT will do the trick UPDATE does, my bad"* @CheshireKatzzze Now i wonder what you have done to fix it..   As MySQL supports  [INSERT INTO .... DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) syntax